# questions about worldly cardinals

Tags: set-theory

A cardinal $\kappa$ is *worldly* if $V_\kappa$ is a model of ZFC.

1. How many $\beth$-fixed points are there smaller than the smallest worldly cardinal?
2. How many worldly cardinals are there smaller than the smallest worldly cardinal of cofinality $\omega_1$?

Comment: See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/719750/462).

Comment: I like the terminology "worldly cardinals"!

Comment: I introduced the "worldly cardinal" terminology at our seminars here in New York, since the concept often comes up and it is very useful to be able to refer to it directly. I'm very glad that the name has stuck!

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins That's something that may be good to add at Cantor's attic: References for where the term is first introduced in the literature.

Comment: OK, I'll do that. As for the literature, I'm not sure what the first reference would be, but I did use the terminology in my recent paper on the multiverse perspective on V=L. I'm not sure if there is an earlier use...

Answer (score 9):

Since $V_\kappa\models{\rm ZFC}$, it satisfies that there are ${\rm ORD}$-many $\beth$-fixed points. But each of those must really be a $\beth$-fixed point because every $V_\alpha$ of $V_\kappa$ is a true $V_\alpha$ of $V$. Thus, there are $\kappa$-many $\beth$-fixed points below $\kappa$.

If $\kappa$ has cofinality $\omega_1$, then the worldly cardinals are unbounded in $\kappa$. Suppose $\xi<\kappa$. Let $V_{\alpha_0}\prec_{\Sigma_1} V_\kappa$ such that $\alpha_0>\xi$.  Now inductively, choose $V_{\alpha_{n+1}}\prec_{\Sigma_{n+1}}V_\kappa$. Let $V_\alpha$ be the union of the $V_{\alpha_n}$. It follows that $V_\alpha\models{\rm ZFC}$ and since the cofinality of $\kappa$ is $\omega_1$ it follows that $\alpha<\kappa$.

Comment: very GOOD answer。

Comment: And one does not even need partial elementarity, or the mention of $\xi$: It suffices that $\alpha_{n+1}>\alpha_n$ and that each $V_{\alpha_{n}}$ satisfies the restriction of $\mathsf{ZFC}$ to $\Sigma_{n}$-replacement. For this, the reflection theorem and some coding suffice, we do not need to formalize satisfiability or any other tool that would be required to produce partially elementary substructures.

Comment: (Though in truth most of this already goes into establishing the relevant instances of reflection.)

Comment: Don't you need $\xi$ to formally verify unboundedness?

Comment: @VictoriaGitman Ah, yes, unboundedness, I somehow forgot and was shooting for just one.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo, I don't believe that your simplification is correct. If all you know that is that $\alpha_{n+1}\gt\alpha_n$ and each $V_{\alpha_n}$ satisfies $\Sigma_n$-replacement, then the limit $V_\alpha$ where $\alpha=\sup_n\alpha_n$ may not satisfy ZFC, and indeed, if $\alpha_{n+1}$ is chosen minimally above $\alpha_n$, then $V_\alpha$ definitely will not satisfy ZFC, since the map $n\mapsto \alpha_n$ will be definable in $V_\alpha$, as $V_\alpha$ can tell all about the theory of $V_{\alpha_n}$, and this will violate replacement in $V_\alpha$.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins Ah, you are right! Sorry for the noise. (For the argument I had in mind, I was assuming additional closure properties of the limit, that do not follow unless we already know it satisfies $\mathsf{ZFC}$. Oh, well...)

Comment: (@VictoriaGitman Sorry for the added confusion.)